# std move result still using copy-contractor

Tags: c++, c++17, unique-ptr, move-semantics

The following code doesn't compile -

```
struct A {
    A() = default;
    A(const A& other) = delete;
};


int main()
{
  auto a = A();
  auto u = std::make_unique<A>(std::move(a));
}
```

While the following does -

```
struct A {
    A() = default;
    A(const A& other) = delete;
    A(A&& other) = default;
};

int main()
{
  auto u = std::make_unique<A>(A());
}
```

The error I got is `call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor`. 
Im using a blaze compiler for cpp-17.

Why does the first code segment not compile? It shouldn't use the copy contractor, just the move one.

Edit: 
Adding     `A(A&& other) = default;` solves the issue.
Does this mean that deleting the copy-contractor also deletes the move-contractor implicitly, and it needs to be added?

Comment: You don't declare the move constructor. See when [**Implicitly-declared move constructor**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor), neither of them is your case, because you have a user declared deleted copy constructor.

Comment: Your second code block also does not compile: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40d5fc3c9e95fd0f

Comment: interesting @NathanOliver, because in https://cpp.sh/  the code does compile (with the  <memory> include).

I don't know which compiler you are using but it probably isn't blaze. 
And even if both shouldn't compile, then why shouldn't they? what is the issue?

Comment: Can't reproduce: When I add `A(A&& other) = default;` (to your first example) the code compiles.

Comment: With proper includes, and adding defaulted move constructor, [the first code block compiles just fine](https://godbolt.org/z/P6f6aTjb7) on modern GCC and clang (not that it does anything useful; even `-O1` reduces it to `return 0;`).

Comment: @NimrodFiat it compiles because you have `A(A&& other) = default;` in code shown in your comment. (In your question that `A(A&& other) = default;` is missing)

Comment: you are right, i'll fix the question. if i add A(A&& other) = default; it does solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By deleting the copy constructor, you also implicitly delete the move constructor (`A(A&& other)`). If you want to use the first code segment, you must define your own custom move constructor (which will depend on the actual data of `A`).

Look at the concepts "rule of 5", "rule of 0" and related links (e.g. [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)) to get a grip on which constructors must be defined.

(by the way, the second code block does not compile on GCC or Clang, as pointed out in the comments. See [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:12,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:12,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:12,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:12),source:%27%23include+%3Cmemory%3E%0A%0Astruct+A+%7B%0A++++A()+%3D+default%3B%0A++++A(const+A%26+other)+%3D+delete%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++auto+u+%3D+std::make_unique%3CA%3E(A())%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:53.36814621409922,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%270%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:58.93617021276596,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:41.06382978723404,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:46.63185378590078,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4). Edit: code in question was changed so this comment is no longer true.)